# How to do IIS Deployment with XML Transformation in Azure-DevOPS Release pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How to create a release pipeline for IIS Deployment with XML Transformation

I create a build pipeline in azure devops.I am planning to create a release pipeline which needs to deploy the build in 3 IIS Websites(DEV,QA,STAG) to on Premise Servers (iam not using Azure servers)

As per my research, i created 3  configs in the application with their environment specific values in each config
When i use the IIS Deploy task,i have an option to select the xml transformation.How does the xml transformation works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these steps below:

Step 1: Create a Asp.net Web Application (Name:**SalesDemo**)

Step 2.1: Create Nested Configs (e.g. web.SalesDemoQA.config, web.SalesDemoStag.config,web.SalesDemoProd.config), Copy to Output Directory: Always)

Sept 2. 2 open your csproj file in a text editor and check the following

```
 <None Include="web.SalesDemoQA.config">
          <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>             
 </None>
```

change the above code to the below code

```
<Content Include="web.SalesDemoQA.config">         
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content >
```

Step 2.3 Sample code in web.SalesDemoQA.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SalesDemo"   connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=SalesDemoDBQA;Integrated Security=True" 
                xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
     </connectionStrings>
```

Step 3: Login  to Azure DevOPS site

Step 4: Create Build Pipeline

Step 4.1: Select a Repsotiory

Step 4.2: Select a Template (Asp.net Template)

Sep  4.3  `msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'`

**Note**: I added the following additional parameters in the msBuildArgs
/p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False

Step 4.4: Publish Build Artifacts

Step 5  Create a Release pipeline

Step 5.1:Create a Stage Name:(SalesDemoQA)

Step 5.2 :Create IIS Web App Manage Task

Step 5.3 :Create IIS Web App Deploy Task

Step 5.4 :Set the (Package or Folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_SalesDemo/drop/SalesDemo.zip;

Step 5.5 :**Check XML transformation option**

Assuming that the web.SalesDemoQA.config file  will be transformed to web.config file.

Note :The Stage Name matches with the config name(www.salesDemo.config)

Comment: You can try this transformation code `<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SalesDemo"   connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=SalesDemoDBQA;Integrated Security=True"          xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Condition(@name='<name in web.config>')"/>
 </connectionStrings>`. I found there may be some mistakes in the exmples given by microsoft site.

Comment: You can go to [this site](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com) to test if the transformation works

Comment: i tried and no luck ..its taking from the release config file only...i tested my transformation code and your suggestion for  transformation code  both worked on the test transformation site

Comment: are configuration file and transform file in the same folder? and add /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False in MSBuild arguements.

Comment: You may already know that if web.release.config exists, transformation will always  take web.release.config first, and then take the web.<stage>.config

Comment: Yes working after adding the /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=False /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False in the MSBuild arguments.And also i updated the steps so that it will be useful for others

Answer (score 2):

Xml transformation takes effect only when the **configuration file**(web.config) and **transform file**(web.`stage`.config) are in the same folder within the specified package. For more information you can check this [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-transformation)

The **transform file** is an XML file that specifies how the Web.config file should be changed when it is deployed. For its syntax you can check this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110))

So in your case, Firstly you should specify a **configuration file** (eg. Web.config) and three **transform files**, the transform file should be named after its environment configuration(eg. web.dev.config, web.qa.config, web.stag.config).

In the these three transform files, specify the elements and attributes that need to be transformed with XDT syntax(check above syntax link)(XML-Document-Transform).

Secondly: you should create three stages named dev, qa, stag respectively in your release pipeline.
[image]

Thirdly: enable `XML transformation` of IIS Web App Deploy task for each stage.
[image]

Hope you can find above helpful?

Comment: I did ..but transformation not applied as expected.I  noticed that the transformation is always taking from www.release.config instead if the web.qa.config ..do we need to specify any settings in build pipeline.note :I used .net template for build pipeline

Comment: Did you enable 'XML transformation' for each stage? as above i updated.

Comment: Yes I enabled 'XML transformation'  and also please refer to my steps below